# Rails 5.1 with Webpacker. Using custom js classes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5.1, webpacker

I'm playing with rails 5.1 and i'm having trouble using a custom class from webpacker in an asset pipeline js file.

My thought was that if I had some utility js class that I wanted to use everywhere I'd add it in packs and then be able to use it in anything on the webpacker side as well as everything on the pipeline side.

```
// app/javascript/packs/stuff.js
class Stuff {
  constructor() {
    console.log("*** building stuff! **")
  }
}
export default Stuff
```

If I want to use that on the webpacker side I can with just adding this to

```
packs/application.js
import Stuff from "./stuff"
let s = new Stuff()
```

No issues there, but then I try to use that class on the pipeline side and I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Stuff is not defined
```

I'm using it like this:

```
// assets/javascripts/users.js
new Stuff();
```

I've added to my layout file:

```
= javascript_pack_tag 'stuff'
```

And I also tried adding to the pipelines application.js

```
//= require stuff
//= require_tree .
```

stuff.js was compiled properly to public/packs/stuff.js and is in the manifest.json

```
{
  "application.js": "http://0.0.0.0:8080/packs/application.js",
  "hello_react.js": "http://0.0.0.0:8080/packs/hello_react.js",
  "stuff.js": "http://0.0.0.0:8080/packs/stuff.js" 
}
```

I've also added this to the assests.rb initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('public/packs')
```

I'm sure i'm missing something small and have just been looking at it for too long to see it.

*----- **UPDATE** -----*

There is a little noise in the original post as I was flailing trying to get stuff to work.  In the end you just need the tip provided by the accepted answer.

In app/javascript/packs/application.js add:

```
import Stuff from "./stuff"
window.Stuff = Stuff
```

And in your layout make sure to have:

```
= javascript_pack_tag 'application'
```

I didn't need to //= require stuff in the pipeline application.js.
I also didn't need to add the public directory in the assets.rb initializer.

To use in a pipeline js file like users.js just make sure you use it after everything has loaded like this:

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  new Stuff();
})
```

Or if you want to inline it in your index.slim or something you can just do:

```
javascript: 
   new Stuff();
```

Once it is setup correctly you'll want to restart the webpack server:

```
./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

Now if you make changes to stuff.js they should be compile and available right away as you would expect.

My final stuff class looks like this:

```
export default class Stuff {
  constructor() {
    console.log("*** building stuff! **")
  }

  more() {
    console.log("--- more stuff ---")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your imported class in `window` in order to use it in your front-end code (asset or in template).  In your pack `application.js` add the following :

```
import Stuff from "./stuff"
window.Stuff = Stuff
```

Then you can use it :

```
var foobar = new window.Stuff();
```

Full stack example here : https://gist.github.com/Aschen/f0a53b0d522688cc46ef77705074c1d2

Comment: Hmm, where would I put that?  I can't really use import on the pipeline side because i'm not using babel there or anything. I tried adding to the webpacker side in the application.js but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, you have to add this lines in webpacker side, in your pack `application.js` (I have updated my response)

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I'm still getting the ReferenceError though.  I recompiled webpacker, restart the server etc.    new Stuff(); in my users.js is still not accessible it seems.

Comment: Try `var foobar = new window.Stuff`

Comment: Progress I think.  That gives the error: Uncaught TypeError: window.Stuff is not a constructor

Comment: Ok I figure it out ! (But I don't know why it's behave like this)
In `users.js` you have to use the following syntax : `var foobar = new window.Stuff()` but in your browser console you can use the one you want.

Comment: Hmm... so that didn't work, but I did see that new Stuff() does work in the browser console.  I noticed if I change my class to window.Stuff = class Stuff {}  then it is available in users.js though.

Comment: Did you launch `./bin/webpack-dev-server` ?

Comment: Yeah.  Seems like the only thing that works is to put window.Stuff = class Stuff {}  in the stuff.js file.  Which i'm not sure is the best way?

Comment: Apparently you can use class from webpack other class defined in the asset pipeline. You can also use webpack class directly in your view by using inline javascript. I've made a few test, you can see them here : https://gist.github.com/Aschen/f0a53b0d522688cc46ef77705074c1d2

Comment: Thanks so much for the examples!  I have it working now.  If it is in users.js I needed to add 
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() { new Stuff();}) 
but in the index.slim you don't need to do that.  The load order saves you I guess.  Thanks for your help!